# How can I filter by comparing a column to its own row items

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a bunch of data being pushed in a google sheet row by row. Each row has a reference number (COL A) and a date (COL D). For every reference number, I want to find the latest updated row. It's necessary that this is done by arrayformula.

[image: Check this image to clarify]

So far I have a combination of arrayformula and filter. However it doesn't work as expected as one of the filter arguments is A2:A=A2:A. Obviously this is always true. What I want it to do is compare A2:A=A2 for row 2, then compare A2:A=A3 for row 3 etc. Without dragging down. Since the data is growing automatically

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),max(filter({D2:D},A2:A=A2:A)),))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16pbGiisFcsrHfrFKowzzkpw03Lw79yACjut96xxyWW4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I understand your problem and could be easily solvable by a `QUERY` FUNCTION and dragging down. But why is necessary to do this with `ARRAYFORMULA`? If you want the `QUERY` solution let me know and I will post it.

Comment: I'm using Zapier to push new data to the sheet based on some trigger events in another app. The data is thus constantly growing. Therefore dragging down is not an option

Comment: @player0 I want to use that column to indicate if the row is the latest updated row for that specific reference number. The data is not necessarily being pushed in chronological order by Zapier

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I copied a link in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in **E1**:

```
={"Last Update"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; SORT({A2:A\ D2:D}; 2; 0); 2; 0)))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

You can paste this either of this formulas in F2 and then drag it down.

```
=QUERY($A$2:$E,"SELECT D WHERE A = '"&A2&"' ORDER BY D desc LIMIT 1")


=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(FILTER({$D$2:$D},$A$2:$A=A2)))
```

*Edit:
Try this formula in F2 and there is no need to drag it down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY(QUERY($A$2:$E,"SELECT A, max(D) WHERE A <> '' GROUP BY A"),"SELECT * OFFSET 1",0),2,FALSE),""))
```

You'll probably have give column F a date format, but it's a one time thing. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can you think of a way to do the same thing without dragging down? This is necessary since there's live data being pushed from another app to the next empty row in the sheet